# Creating a method containing image imported from files

Tags: java, image, import

I wanted to create method out of `//create textures` section to shorten the `run()` , but if I do and pass the images from `//import` section as arguments, then call it like:

`createTextures(texture, texture2,ballTextureImport, greenFlashImport, blueFlashImport);`

the method drawGraphics can't see them.

`drawGraphics()` is just repeated `add(everyParameter);`

Here's part of the code inside `run()`:

```
    // import
    Image texture = getImage(getCodeBase(), "texture.png");
    Image texture2 = getImage(getCodeBase(), "texture2.png");
    Image ballTextureImport = getImage(getCodeBase(), "ballTexture.png");
    Image greenFlashImport = getImage(getCodeBase(), "greenFlash.png");
    Image blueFlashImport = getImage(getCodeBase(), "blueFlash.png");

    // create textures
    GImage paddleLeftTexture = new GImage(texture);
    GImage paddleRightTexture = new GImage(texture2);
    GImage ballTexture = new GImage(ballTextureImport);
    GImage greenFlash = new GImage(greenFlashImport, -250, 0);
    GImage blueFlash = new GImage(blueFlashImport, -250, 0);
    paddleLeftTexture.setSize(WIDTH + 1, HEIGHT + 1);
    paddleRightTexture.setSize(WIDTH + 1, HEIGHT + 1);
    ballTexture.setSize(BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
    greenFlash.setSize(100, 300);
    blueFlash.setSize(100, 300);

    // make objects
    GOval ball = makeBall();
    GRect paddleLeft = makePaddle();
    GRect paddleRight = makePaddle();

    drawGraphics(ball, paddleLeftTexture, paddleRightTexture, ballTexture,
            greenFlash, blueFlash, counter, paddleLeft, paddleRight,
            aiScore, playerScore);
```

the remaining arguments from `drawGraphics()` are created earlier in `run()` and in `//make objects` and look fine (are not underlined in red).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to create a `GImage` type method instead of `void` and create textures one by one.

```
    private GImage createTexture(String importedImage, int width, int height) {
    Image importResult = getImage(getCodeBase(), importedImage);
    GImage textureResult = new GImage(importResult);
    textureResult.setSize(width, height);
    return textureResult;
}
```

and then, in `run()` method i have

```
// make objects
    GImage paddleLeftTexture = createTexture("texture.png", WIDTH + 1,
            HEIGHT + 1);
    GImage paddleRightTexture = createTexture("texture2.png", WIDTH + 1,
            HEIGHT + 1);
    GImage ballTexture = createTexture("ballTexture.png", (int) BALL_SIZE,
            (int) BALL_SIZE);
    GImage greenFlash = createTexture("greenFlash.png", 100, 300);
    GImage blueFlash = createTexture("blueFlash.png", 100, 300);
    GOval ball = makeBall();
    GRect paddleLeft = makePaddle();
    GRect paddleRight = makePaddle();
    greenFlash.setLocation(-200, 0);
    blueFlash.setLocation(-200, 0);

    // generate GUI
    drawGraphics(ball, paddleLeftTexture, paddleRightTexture, ballTexture,
            greenFlash, blueFlash, counter, paddleLeft, paddleRight,
            aiScore, playerScore);
```